# To-do list app using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, to-do-list

I created a simple todo kind of app using JavaScript. It is working fine but the code which I wrote is not proper. Please review my code and improve it if it is needed.

```
$(function () {
    var todo = new Todo('contents');

    $('.addBtn').on('click', function() {
        var name = $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').val();
        todo.add(name);
    });

    $('.contents').on('click', '.remove', function() {
        var el = $(this).parent();
        todo.remove(el);
    });

    $('.contents').on('click', '.update', function() {
        var dom = $(this);
        todo.addUpdateField(dom);
    });

    $('.contents').on('click', '.updateBtn', function() {
        var el = $(this);
        todo.update(el);
    });
});
```

Here is my todo.js file

```
var Todo = function(c) {
    var contents = $('.' + c),
    name;

    add = function (name) {
        if(name != "") {
            var div = $('<div class="names"></div>');
            div.append('<span>' + name + '</span>');
            div.append("<button class='update' class='update'>Edit</button>");
            div.append("<button class='remove' name='remove'>Remove</button>");
            contents.prepend(div);
            $('.name').val('').focus();
        }
        return;
    },

    addUpdateField = function (dom) {
        var name = dom.parent().find('span').text(),
            field = $('<input type="text" value="' + name + '" />'),
            update = $('<button class="updateBtn">Update</button>');

        return dom.parent().html('').append(field).append(update);
    },

    update = function(el) {
        var val = el.parent().find('input').val();
        el.parent().html('<span>' + val + '</span>')
        .append('<button class="update" class="update">Edit</button>')
        .append('<button class="remove" class="remove">Remove</button>');
    },

    remove = function (el) {
        return el.remove();
    };

    return {
        add             : add,
        update          : update,
        remove          : remove,
        addUpdateField  : addUpdateField
    };
};
```

Comment: You have leaking globals because of the semi-colon after `name;` (replace it with `,`).

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @st-boost No it is not homework assignment. I am learning modular javascript and want to improve my coding. Since here are professional javascript developer on this forum so I thought this would be the best place for me to ask for improvement in my code.

Comment: @al0neevenings You forgot to share the HTML.

Comment: @al0neevenings Ok, just asking because your wording reminded me of a homework assignment. I hope you find what you're looking for.

Comment: I would suggest possibly putting all instances of hard-coded html like this: `'<button class="update" class="update">Edit</button>'` into their own variables at the top. This way, if you ever need to make a change to all of the 'Edit' buttons you can do this with one simple line change instead of multiple. This isn't a big concern with this project since the most one of these buttons are used is twice, but I think you can see the benefit to this.

Answer (score 2):

As I read it, you want:

- one `<div class="names">` per todo (in this case inside `.contents`) surrounding the todo text in a `span` and the buttons "Edit" / "Remove"
- on clicking "Edit", the `span` is exchanged for an `input` field and an "Update" button, "Edit" and "Remove" are removed.
- on clicking "Update", the prior state with the new text is recreated (`span`, Edit, Remove)

After you follow [Inkbug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/14938/inkbug)`s advice from his comment, you should probably do this:

- cache the todo root element (`var todoRoot = $(...);`)
- rename `addUpdateField`/`.update` to `edit`/`.edit` and `updateBtn` to `update` - consistent with the button texts and easier to read
- change the api of your todo.js functions. For update / edit / remove, just use the dom node of the div as the argument:

  ```
  function(target, action) {
      todoRoot.on('click', target, function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          action.call(todo, $(this).parents('.names').first());
      });
  }

  bindClick('.remove', todo.remove);
  bindClick('.edit',   todo.edit);
  bindClick('div',     todo.update);
  ```
- don't use that many appends. Put it all in a string (that can contain more than one DOM node!)
- don't create / delete all the nodes. Create all three buttons, use [`.toggleClass(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and CSS to make all buttons/fields disappear that you don't need. That moves all your HTML into the `add` function and goes easy on the DOM
- move the bindings into the `Todo` function. You don't want to have to remember to bind these events for every Todo list you create